# .Sum() function returns wrong result

Tags: c#, linq

The data in database is :

```
table Bill      
ActualAmount    PaidAmount
150              (null)
150              (null)
2400              400
```

When I execute the code:

```
var bills = _dbContext.Bills.Where(x => x.Customer.Id == customer.Id);
var amount = bills.Sum(x => (x.ActualAmount - x.PaidAmount??0));
```

it return 2000.

if I execute:

```
var amount = bills.Sum(x => (x.ActualAmount))- bills.Sum(x => (x.PaidAmount));
```

it return 2300 (I want this result).

Can anyone tell why??

Comment: Eh at a pinch it's operator precedence (I can't remember the rules for precedence) `bills.Sum(x => (x.ActualAmount - (x.PaidAmount??0)))`

Comment: @ta.speot.is You're right. It correctly returns 700 if you add the parentheses.

Comment: @john but OP doesn't want 700... *it return 2300 (I want this result)*

Comment: @ta.speot.is That may be so, but their working example also returns 700 for that data set, which suggests their example is different to the numbers 2000 and 2300. Likewise, performing the calculation `(150 - 0) + (150 - 0) + (2400 - 2000)` in my head also results in 700.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake.the database should be      
ActualAmount    PaidAmount
150              (null)
150              (null)
2400              400

Comment: Please edit the question rather than leaving this important information buried in a comment.

Comment: _First rule of programming, it's always `your` fault_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add parenthesis around the (x.PaidAmount ?? 0), that'll take precedence over the subtraction.  However, you get the result 700 and not 2300.

### UPDATE

Changed the PaidAmount for the 3rd record to 400 resulting in 2300 for the sum.  Also updated the fiddle demo.

Something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Bill> bills = new List<Bill>();
        bills.Add(new Bill() {ActualAmount = 150, PaidAmount = null});
        bills.Add(new Bill() {ActualAmount = 150, PaidAmount = null});
        // bills.Add(new Bill() {ActualAmount = 2400, PaidAmount = 2000});
        bills.Add(new Bill() {ActualAmount = 2400, PaidAmount = 400});

        var amount = bills.Sum(x => (x.ActualAmount - (x.PaidAmount ?? 0)));
        Console.WriteLine(amount);
    }
}

public class Bill
{
    public double? ActualAmount {get; set;}
    public double? PaidAmount {get; set;}
}
```

Result

```
2300
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EU6JRx)